# Installing nginx with Webdav support

Tags: nginx, openssl, homebrew

I am using Mac OS.
Installing nginx with brew:

```
brew install nginx
```

But this nginx doesn't have webdav support.

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "dav_methods"
```

So i found that there is [nginx/full](http://brew.sh/homebrew-nginx/)
Installing it with `--with-upload-module`

```
brew install homebrew/nginx/nginx-full --with-upload-module
```

It says, I have no OpenSSL:

```
checking for OpenSSL library ... not found
checking for OpenSSL library in /usr/local/ ... not found
checking for OpenSSL library in /usr/pkg/ ... not found
checking for OpenSSL library in /opt/local/ ... not found
```

So I tried to install it too:

```
brew install --force openssl
```

Got: `Warning: openssl-1.0.2j already installed, it's just not linked.`

How can I solve this?

Comment: `nginx-full` was removed from the main homebrew and is at this time a community supported tap `denji/nginx` https://github.com/denji/homebrew-nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed this problem by installing nginx from the [source](http://nginx.org/en/download.html)

And then configure with webDav support:

```
./configure --with-http_dav_module
```